# Bitmap Resizing

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I get a NullPointerException error in my code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

I have a bitmap which I decoded from bytes that I received from a web service. I don't understand this error. Can you please help me to correct the code?

I'm new to Android programming and I'm eager to learn!

Here's my code:

```
public class CatListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> alNames;
    ArrayList<String> alImages;
    ArrayList<String> alId;
    private Activity context;
    float cornerRadius = 50.0f;
    ImageView imageFlag;

    public CatListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> alNames, ArrayList<String> alImages,
            ArrayList<String> alId) {
        super(context, R.layout.category_list, alNames);
        this.context = context;
        this.alNames = alNames;
        this.alImages = alImages;
        this.alId = alId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null)
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list, null, true);
        TextView textViewCountry = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtcatname);

        imageFlag = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.catimage);

        textViewCountry.setText(alNames.get(position));
        if (String.valueOf(alImages.get(position)) != "") {
            byte[] decode = Base64.decode(alImages.get(position), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decode, 0, decode.length);
            bitmapResize(bitmap);
        }
        return row;
    }

    public void bitmapResize(Bitmap imageBitmap) {

        float widthbmp = imageBitmap.getWidth();
        float lengthbmp = imageBitmap.getHeight();
        // Get Screen width
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        float hight = displaymetrics.heightPixels / 3;
        float width = displaymetrics.widthPixels / 3;

        int convertHighet = (int) hight, convertWidth = (int) width;

        // high length
        if (lengthbmp > hight) {
            convertHighet = (int) hight - 20;
            imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, convertWidth, convertHighet, true);
        }

        // high width
        if (widthbmp > width) {
            convertWidth = (int) width - 20;
            imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, convertWidth, convertHighet, true);
            imageFlag.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess in code Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decode, 0, decode.length),you got a null bitmap,so could you post your a value of alImages.get(position).

Comment: your bitmap object is null to avoid it simply check using if statement for null.

Comment: if you have url use any image loading libraries like glide or picasso.

Comment: thanq u frnds i will

Comment: if (String.valueOf(alImages.get(position)) != "") here am checking whether is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please check if `byte[] decode` is returning non null value.
Then you add following line of code before: 
`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decode, 0, decode.length);`

`BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;`

you can use the bmOptions like this:
`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decode, 0, decode.length,bmOptions);`

To understand the implementation you can refer to this link :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds

Happy coding!

Comment: thanqs sir i got output